# What are inputs and outputs in tf.saved_model.simple_save?

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, save, restore

In tf.saved_model.simple_save, there are 4 params:

- session, the session
- export_dir, the dir where the model will be saved
- inputs, **what it this?**
- outputs, **what is this?**

I've been reading how to [simple_save](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#simple_save) but I haven't been able to figure out what to put in these two parameters (inputs and outputs). I know the model must have input values so that it can be either trained or predict. So I don't know what these two parameters should contain and wether they should map variables inside the model or what...

The docs aren't that great so any explaining would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @Ankit no, not really. I am currently not working with TensorFlow... but no answers as you see... do you have any insights?